# Validating a date field in a calendar

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want to validate a date field calendar, where dates in the calendar cannot be selected to greater than today. The below code is in the tips of the eval field like "

**set a variable called 'return' to true to stop this date from being selected.**

> var diff = new Date().compare(new Date(date));
>       var result = diff < 0 ? true : false;

Now I want the same intended result that is the dates in the calendar cannot be selected greater than today.

Comment: Please try to use *descriptive* titles.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new Date() < new Date(date);
```

Comment: Sorry Darin Dimitrov, but I am totally a newbie to javascript. now how do pass the value of var result to my calendar field. 
Can it be like return var result;

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Darin Dimitrov's answer with Pawan's response.

```
inputField.onchange = function(){
    return (new Date() < new Date(this.value))? true: this.value = "";
}
```

Comment: No, I am not getting the result on insertion of the above code in the eval field.
I am still able to select all the dates in the calendar

Comment: Your question was how to validate a date field, not to disable dates on a calendar. Could you provide a sample of your calendar code?

Comment: It's inbuilt joomla calendar. I am using only a date field where there is a option to insert javascript code with a little hint as I mentioned above, which will enable me to disable the dates from being selected.

Comment: You'll still need to provide a sample of how your calendar is created if you hope to resolve the issue. Which Joomla calendar, if it's defined at server side, what scripting language are you using there, if not how is it instantiated on the client side?